# Executing an oracle variable string as I do in SQL Server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, dynamic-sql

In SQL Server I can do something like:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @VAR = SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES

EXECUTE(@VAR)
```

How can I execute a string that I've created inside a variable in Oracle?

This is the query:

```
DECLARE BUSCACOLUNA  VARCHAR(2000);
BEGIN

 BUSCACOLUNA:= 'SELECT  '' SELECT '' || LTRIM(listagg ( '' , '' || ''"'' || T1.COLUMN_NAME || ''"'' || '' AS '' ||''"''|| T2.DESCRICAO ||''"''  ) within group  ( order by t1.column_name ),'' , '') || '' FROM TABELA_ENTRADA ''
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS T1
    INNER JOIN TABBASE T2
      ON T1.COLUMN_NAME=T2.NO_COL_TABBASE
    WHERE T1.TABLE_NAME=''TABELA_ENTRADA''
    AND T2.CD_CONTEUDO_ARQUIVO= ''X''';


 END;
```

The result of that dynamic SQL is something like:

```
  SELECT C1 AS B1, C2 AS B2...FROM TABLE
```

And I would like to execute this SELECT by executing the VARIABLE.

I tried with a loop, with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` but the query only returns:

> anonymous block completed

So I can understand it's working. If it was an UPDATE or INSERT, it would work, But I would like the return of that.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results of the SELECT statement?  You'd either need to consume the data in your PL/SQL block or you'd need to return it to the calling application.  If you want to return it to the calling application, you could define a stored procedure that has an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` and use the dynamic SQL statement to open the cursor.  But I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: I just want to show it on the screen, like a normal result set, as I do with SQL Server.

Comment: That's not as easy as it is in SQL Server.  What front-end are you using where you want the data to be printed out?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you use (for dynamic SQL):

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
```

Or

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE()
```

Like the examples here: https://www.guru99.com/dynamic-sql-pl-sql.html